# <a href or <asp:hyperlink.....tag does not render at runtime

Tags: asp.net, html

i am trying to display a simple div with hyperlink that represents `x` 
like this:
[image]

So, when my run my app i see the div but i dont see the `x` which is `<a href tag`
and here is my code:

```
<div class="success"><a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>status message here...</div>
```

and when i looked at the source of the page this is what it renders:

```
<div id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentMain_ContentMain_employee_status" class="success" style="display:block;">status message here...</div>
```

and then i tried with `<asp:hyperlink....`

```
 <div class="success" id="divStatus" visible="false" runat="server"><asp:HyperLink id="success" runat="server" CssClass="close" Text="&times;"></asp:HyperLink></div>
```

and i still dont see href tag, what is going on here and why i am not able to render the `<a href or <asp:hyperlnk tag` any clue?

Comment: Are you setting the InnerHtml property of `divSuccess` in the code behind? that would erase its static contents (the hyperlink).

Comment: Time, yes i am writing InnerHtml `divSuccess.InnerHtml ="status message here...` if thats the case that erasing its static contents then what is the alternate?

Comment: Posted a couple solutions for you.

Answer (score 1):

> i am writing InnerHtml divSuccess.InnerHtml ="status message here...
>   if thats the case that erasing its static contents then what is the
>   alternate?

If `divStatus` contains controls that you want to keep, then you can append HTML to it by using a Literal control and adding it to the controls collection, like:

```
var lit = new Literal();
lit.Text = "my text or <strong>html</strong>";
this.divStatus.Controls.Add(lit);
```

Alternatively, you could use another control *inside* `divStatus` and alter its inner HTML:

```
<div id="divStatus" runat="server">
    <a id="lnk1">This is the link that we don't want to be removed.</a>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" id="litStatusHtml" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how i able to solved my question

```
divStatus.InnerHtml = "<a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a>" + "status message here...";
```